# fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 404 error

Tags: theming

Our drupal site uses `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` through bootstrap v3.3.2. But I am getting `404` for the `file fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2`.
Is it some issue with the bootstrap? What is proper way to fix this?

Comment: What webserver and version?  Apache?  IIS?

Comment: we use Apache/2.2.15

Answer (score 1):

wget https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/raw/master/app/assets/fonts/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
and move it to the openatrium/themes/oa_radix/assets/font directory.
Here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2625784